# replace this jquery .css() function with .animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this code.

```
jQuery("#box").bind('mousemove', function(e){
       jQuery(".mousetail").css('background-position-x', (e.pageX - this.offsetTop - 437)+'px');
});
```

That makes mousetail follow the cursor. But when i bring mouse over the box (away from the mousetail), the mousetail will instantly appear at that position. I want it to reach there with animation.
Also, background-position-x doesn't seem to work in Firefox. can someone please tell me the correct way to use `background-position:0px *based on co-ord*` in the code (i don't know the correct syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is very similar, it takes one `CSS` argument, then a duration argument, then a callback (what to execute when the animation is complete)

```
jQuery(".mousetail").animate({
  'background-position-x' : (e.pageX - this.offsetTop - 437)+'px' //Use Colon instead of comma
  }, 300, //This number sets the duration of the animation
  function() {alert('animation complete!');} //Callback function
);
```

Comment: After the first movement (which goes fine), if i move the mouse to new location again, the mousetail will move very slowly for 3 seconds or so and then quickly slide to new location. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
jQuery("#box").bind('mousemove', function(e){
   jQuery(".mousetail").animate({'background-position-x': (e.pageX - this.offsetTop - 437)+'px'});
});
```

Comment: Did _you_ try that? That is not the correct way to call `.animate()`

Comment: Whoops! I'm so used to passing an object for `$.css({})` that I didn't even check the parameters. My bad. Correcting...